# fixed leading 0's with pgfmath

Tags: formatting, pgfmath

I want to calculate a time being printed using `pgfmath`. I have some code similiar to this:

```
\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x,60))}\pgfmathresult O'clock
```

but if the result is between 0 and 9 my time being displayed is something like `11:2` instead of `11:02`. Can I force fixed zeros at the front? I only found something to get them at the end.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can use `\ifdim` to test the result. `\ifdim\pgfmathresult<10 0\pgfmathresult\else\pgfmathresult\fi~O'clock`

Comment: A slightly convoluted workaround would be to divide the number by 100 and print the result without the leading zero and without the decimal separator: `11:\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x,60))/100}\pgfmathprintnumber[skip 0.=true, dec sep={}, fixed]{\pgfmathresult}`

Comment: @Jake: Awesome idea ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgfmath` can use strings in its calculations, so you could test whether your result is less than 10 and add a `0` in that case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {2,4,...,14}{
    11:\pgfmathparse{mod(\x,60)<10?"0":{},int(mod(\x,60))}\pgfmathresult\hspace{1em}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another workaround would be to divide the number by 100 and print the output without the leading zero and without the decimal marker:

```
11:\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x,60))/100}\pgfmathprintnumber[skip 0.=true, dec sep={}, fixed]{\pgfmathresult}
```