# xtick latex hour option

Tags: pgfplots, date

I have many graph using date as x axis, and I wonder if there is an option of xtick to put a tick every hour automatically and not writting every tick like that :

```
xtick = {
{2018-04-27 05:00},
{2018-04-27 06:00},
{2018-04-27 07:00},
{2018-04-27 08:00},
{2018-04-27 09:00},
{2018-04-27 10:00},
{2018-04-27 11:00},
{2018-04-27 12:00},
{2018-04-27 13:00},
{2018-04-27 14:00},
{2018-04-27 15:00},
{2018-04-27 16:00},
{2018-04-27 17:00},
{2018-04-27 18:00},
{2018-04-27 19:00},
{2018-04-27 20:00}
}
```

Cause I've tried this, that didn't worked and that I know works for years alone :

```
xtick = {
{2018-04-27 05:00},
{2018-04-27 06:00},
...,
{2018-04-27 20:00}
}
```

Here is an exemple of what I would like to get in the end :

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VJOc.jpg

Thank you !

Comment: Where do the X and Y values come from? If it is from a file, then https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267452/xy-plot-from-date-time-data-table-using-pgfplots might be interesting, otherwise maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133857/how-to-use-a-macro-inside-tick-definition-in-pgfplots. Can you make a complete MWE that shows a plot with the manual list of xticks? That will help in understanding the problem and finding a solution.

Comment: If you need to cover more than one day, you might use the Unix time which is just a number of seconds since specified time therefore easy to increment. Then you can convert it to more readable format using methods from this queation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147707/131547

Comment: @Marijn Well I added a picture, but the link didn't showed it :(

Comment: @SPQR211 I'm gonna look at this and come back if needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only the hour changes, you might want to consider using only the hour as a ticklabel.

---

If you definitely want the entire time/date, you can use the `xticklabel` option as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xticklabel = {%
                \pgfmathparse{int(\tick)<10?"0":{},int(\tick)}%
                2018-04-27 \pgfmathresult:00%
            },
            xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
            xtick distance=1,
            xmin = 5,
            xmax = 20,
        ]
            \addplot+[domain=5:20] ({x},{x^2});   
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76168/74459) to add a leading zero to the hour.

Result:

[image]

Comment: When i try your xticklabel, I get something weird showing : "2018-04-27 1987:00" at each tick : https://imgur.com/frxM0h2

Comment: I found a way ! The xtick distance that you use is enough to make it, just by dividing 1 (day) per 24 (number of hours) and it works ! Thank you for your interest in the question

Comment: @HugoVernier-Lambert I don't see what you mean in the image you attached, and I don't really understand what you mean with your fix, but I am glad that I could be of help.

Comment: https://imgur.com/2NrBojh I've put a wrong image link sorry, here is the one showing the probleme